# Stressed "would" vs. stressed "will": which explanation is more precise?

Tags: modal-verbs

> We can use *would* to express annoyance or irritation at **things that are
>   happening  now**. There is usually a sense that this is typical, or not
>   very surprising.
>
> > You *would* say *that*!    ( it's typical of you, and it's annoying ).
> >
> > *Wouldn't* you just know *it*! ( I knew that would happen — and it's
> >     annoying ).
>
> --Page 78 (Macmillan - Inside Out English Grammar in Context Advanced)

However:

> Stressed *will* can be used to criticise people's typical behaviour.
>
> > She *WILL* fall in love with the wrong people.
> >
> > Well, if you *WILL* keep telling people what you think of them ...
>
> Stressed *would* can also be used to criticise **a single past action** - 
>   the meaning  is 'that's typical of you'.
>
> > You *WOULD* tell Mary about the party - I didn't want to invite her.
>
> -- 633.7, Michael Swan's, Practical English Usage.

I would think these two versions don't agree with each other. Which one is more precise and correct?

If PEU is right, the example in Macmillan would be "You *WILL* say *that*!"

Besides, is "*Wouldn't* you just know *it*!" a rhetorical question? How to parse it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you reproduced the [*italics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use-mention_distinction) from the original.

Comment: OK, it is done! Thx for your advice! I'll stick to it. @snailplane

Comment: It's not that either one is wrong (they both give valid uses), but that neither is complete.  Now that you've read both of them, you have a fuller picture of how and when you can use the stressed *would*.-

Comment: If I understand this aright, you're saying you think *"You **would** say that!"* and *"She **will** date no-hopers!"* are very different. But to me there's no conflict, and they're essentially the same usage. The first is in the past tense because *you already said it* (or "conditional" because that's what you say *whenever that situation arises*). The second is present tense because *she keeps doing it*.

Comment: So I can say  "You _WILL_ say that!" instead of  "You _WOULD_ say that!", and the intended meaning remains unchanged, right? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: These are mostly quite stylised/affected/dated forms, so you're very much in a tricky area here. For example, I really wouldn't expect to hear Swan's final example from "ordinary people" today (it sounds like something from a historical drama). But *"You **would** say that! [wouldn't you?]"* means *"It's typical/normal for you to say what you just said"*. We don't normally say *"You **will** say that!"*, but in principle it would mean the same. Whereas *"You **will** keep saying that!"*, means something more like *"You persistently and willfully say that, but I wish you wouldn't"*.

Comment: I agree. Some parts of PEU are quite out-of-date. Perhaps PEU needs further revision. Can you plz recommend any books to me which have a separation between ordinary usages and archaic ones? @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: I don't know of any such, but it would be a very difficult area to address. Things change, which is why even the most accurate guide can soon be out of date. But more importantly, much of the information would be somewhat subjective/localised. Dated/archaic forms often survive in localised geographical or sociological "pockets" where they remain perfectly "normal" long after the mainstream has moved on. Plus of course, every now and then an antiquated form comes back into fashion, sometimes in a big way.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng I don't see any real conflict between the two books. I think what Hellion said is fair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my ear, the PEU examples are both colloquially natural and accurately described, while the Macmillan examples, although colloquial, are somewhat misleadingly described: *things that are happening now* might be better expressed as *things that have just happened or have just been reported*. But that's a minor criticism.

All these examples exhibit the same basic use of *will* to express habitual or characteristic action. In this sense (like all the modals in all their senses) this habitual *will* employs its tensed forms, and particularly the past-tense form, to express nuances which may have little or nothing to do with tense. Speaking very broadly,

- Ordinary unstressed uses usually express simple habit—behavior repeated frequently over a long period of time—and tense has its usual significance of present or past reference:

  > When he's preoccupied with a problem he will often pace up and down for hours.
  >   When I was a child we would always go to my grandmother's for Thanksgiving dinner.
- When *will* or *would* is stressed, the sense is somewhat different: the habitual action is represented as perversely deliberate.  And the tenses are employed somwhat differently, too. The present-tense form generally signifies that the subject currently makes a habit of the perverse behavior:

  > She *will* keep falling in love with the wrong people *is rhetorically equivalent to* She insists on falling in love with the wrong people.

  But the past-tense form, although refers to a past action, does not express repeated action in the past but represents the subject's behavior on a single occasion as characteristically perverse:

  > You *would* tell Mary about the party ... Even though I asked you not to tell anybody without checking with me, you just can't control yourself around her.
  >
  > A: He said it was all Jack's fault.
  >   B: Well, he *would* say that, wouldn't he. Nothing is ever his fault, oh no!